# JQuery - Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have create a form.html like this

```
<form class="smallForm" id="form" onsubmit="event.returnValue = false; return false">
 Name: <input type = "text" name = "domain" />
      <select name="domain_ext" class="inputAuto">
        <option value=".com">.com</option>
      </select>
     <input type = "submit" />
</form>
```

In test.php, i try to create a curl get method

```
error_reporting(E_ERROR );
$a = $_POST["domain"];
$b = $_POST["domain_ext"];

function httpGet($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();  

    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_URL,$url);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,true);
//  curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_HEADER, false); 

    $output=curl_exec($ch);

    curl_close($ch);
    return $output;
}
echo httpGet("https://xxxx.jsp?domain=$a$b");
```

To let the result display directly under the form table, i create a js file with code:

```
 function domain_ajax_click_ffactory(mode) {
  'use strict';
  var form_domain = 'domain';
  var form_domain_ext = 'domain_ext';

  return function () {
    domain_loading(mode);

    var domain =
      $('#domain_' + mode + '_form input[name=' + form_domain + ']').val();
    var domain_ext =
      $('#domain_' + mode + '_form select[name=' + form_domain_ext + ']').val();

       var enc_domain = encodeURIComponent(domain);
        var enc_domain_ext = encodeURIComponent(domain_ext);

        if (!domain || !domain_ext) {
          domain_loaded(mode);
        } else {
          $.ajax({
            url: '//xxxx.com/test.php',
            type: 'get',
            dataType: 'json',
            data:
              'domain=' + enc_domain +
              '&domain_ext=' + enc_domain_ext +
              '&form=domain_' + mode + '_form'
          }).always(domain_ajax_always_ffactory(mode, enc_domain, enc_domain_ext));
        }
      };
    }


    function domain_ajax_always_ffactory(mode, enc_domain, enc_domain_ext) {
  'use strict';
  var f;

  switch (mode) {
  case 'whois':
    f = function(data, status, jqxhr) {
      $('#domain_whois_loaded').text(data.domain_whois.result);
      domain_loaded(mode);
    };
    break;
  }

  return f;
}
```

However, when i enter the text field and submit the form, there is no result and i saw an error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'result' of undefined" at console log.  I really need someone help on this. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Check response from your php-script.

Comment: If i create another form with <form action = "test.php" method = "POST">, ii can get the result, but the url link will redirect to test.php

Comment: what i want is that i still will stay at form.html after submit the form, and the result display under the form

Comment: Change it to this than `<form action = "form.html" method = "POST">`

Comment: but that one cannot get the result form test.php

Comment: Alright than you need to combine your html and php file into one php file, with isset you can call the php when you use the button.

Comment: Is that anyway without combining the php file and html? cause as i know jquery can do it, but i not sure why Cannot read property 'result' of undefined